# Reference request: SGA7

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I want to read SGA7. Without considering the others SGA and EGA, Which are the textbooks for monodromy theory?

Comment: Have fun with the bi-extension construction of the monodromy pairing.  More seriously, surely you can give *some* context for your motivation, or indication of what you plan to get out of this "read".  There is a huge amount of material in there, insofar as the phrase "monodromy theory" is really too vague to be a baseline for giving meaningful advice.  Please offer something more specific about your goals (and some indication of your background would not be irrelevant; e.g., have you read SGA1 and/or SGA2 and what do you know about abelian varieties, Neron models, and p-divisible groups?)

Comment: You will need more than textbooks to be able to read SGA 7! Anyway, you may start with the very classical (and beautiful) *Singular points of complex hypersurfaces* by Milnor (Princeton UP). But be aware that it is a long way from this to SGA 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following book will be helpful:
http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-7643-7535-5 (The Monodromy Group, by Henryk Zoladek).

Answer (score 1):

You may find Illusie's text helpfull: http://gc83.perso.sfr.fr/GTIM/PDF%20GROUPE%20DE%20TRAVAIL/Ducros/Illusie.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To start with:

Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups, by Tamás Szamuely
(The theorem in section 3.4 about the absolute Galois group go $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is amazing and enlightening.)

And then:

Milne, James S. (1980), Étale cohomology, Princeton Mathematical Series 33, Princeton University Press

Deligne, Pierre, ed. (1977), Séminaire de Géométrie Algébrique du Bois Marie — Cohomologie étale (SGA 41⁄2), Lecture notes in mathematics (in French) 569